# Recursive function that computes sum of n integers C++

Tags: c++, recursion, sum

I have to make a recursive function that will compute the sum of the first n integer in an array of at least n integers. I believe I have the function complete the cout statement however is causing an error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n = 0;
int array[];

int sum(int array[], int n);

int main()
{
    cout << sum(array, 4)<< endl;
    return 0;
}//end main

int sum(int array[], int n)
{
    if(n <= 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        return array[0] + sum(array + 1, n-1);
    }
}// end Compute
```

Here is the error:

> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: That's not the complete error message, because the linker will also tell you *which* external is unresolved.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please use the `homework` tag.

Comment: The rest of the error message might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `array` is never defined anywhere and `int array[];` is not valid syntax (but for some reason your compiler is treating it as an `extern` declaration or something). Change the invalid syntax to define it:

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // for example
```

Comment: `int array[]` is not invalid syntax per se; it's only invalid in this case, because the size of `array` is not known. `extern int array[4]; int array[];` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that the undefined external symbol is `array`, because you never gave it a size or values.

Since it's an unsized array, it's treated as an extern declaration rather than a definition. If you initialize the array it should compile and link.

```
int array[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };
```